# Optimization of specific very slow query

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, max, sql-delete

I wrote this query after optimizing a php script that did the same thing but using 3 different queries and 2 loops while...and this php script took over 6 hours to run...
So i've compress all in a simple query that to the same job without any loops...

```
DELETE table  FROM table WHERE id IN  (
    SELECT id from(
        SELECT MAX(data_elab) as data_elab_new, count(*) as volte,t1.* FROM (
            SELECT * from table ORDER BY data_elab DESC
        )t1
        group by cod_dl,issn,variante,add_on having volte>1
    )t2
);
```

Note:the server is very old (Windows,3gb of ram,32bit),table size 204 MB,100.000 row,20 columns,only id is primary key,no indexes.

This query took only 20sec...the delete is the problem....

```
SELECT id from(
        SELECT MAX(data_elab) as data_elab_new, count(*) as volte,t1.* FROM (
            SELECT * from table ORDER BY data_elab DESC
        )t1
        group by cod_dl,issn,variante,add_on having volte>1
    )t2
```

The problem is that I thought of speeding up the operation a lot but actually after more than two hours the query did not complete and continues to works...

Any advice to optimize this query or I did something wrong in the query?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of the order by?  You're aggregating it in the next step, so the order by is probably unnecessary and slowing down the query.

Comment: And you should definitely have indexes on data_elab, cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on.  And you should only be selecting cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on.  You aren't using the other columns, so you don't need to select them.  Still, the table is small, so I'm not sure why it would take so long.

Comment: Could you add query explain plan to this question? explain <sql>

Comment: The intent of the query is not entirely clear to me. It kind of looks like you're trying to remove something like the "most recent" for each "X". But if it actually works as intended, it is only through side effects that are not guaranteed; MAX serves absolutely no purpose and, as the `id` is not a part of the grouping criteria, which `id` for each combination of `cod_dl,issn,variante,add_on` is effectively a random selection from the id values that happen to accompany that combination.

Comment: -Order by is very important to take only the row  with the max data_elab
-Index can cause problem with low ram ?ok i 'll remove * and add only usefull colums

Comment: The intent of query is find the group of cod_dl,issn,variante,add_on that occur more than 1 time then find the max data_elab  of any single group and delete that row. right? @uueerdo

Comment: That is what I thought. That query has no guarantee the `id` value will be one that accompanied the max data_elab value... it might, but it is not guaranteed. What should happen, if it is possible, when there are two records with the same `cod_dl,issn,variante,add_on` and the same `data_elab`?

Comment: @uueerdo data_elab is univocal inside the "group" so no problem...

Comment: Could you post the RESULT of the this 20 second query?
SELECT id from(
        SELECT MAX(data_elab) as data_elab_new, count(*) as volte,t1.* FROM (
            SELECT * from table ORDER BY data_elab DESC
        )t1
        group by cod_dl,issn,variante,add_on having volte>1
    )t2        
Once you have the ID, why not just DELETE where ID = result?

Comment: What percentage of the table are you deleting?  If high, there are better ways.

Comment: Don't do all this work `SELECT  MAX(data_elab) as data_elab_new, count(*) as volte,t1.*` only to use _just_ `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data_elab` is never repeated for any combination of `cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on` *(I am assuming that is what "univocal" means)*, this the form the query you need should take:

```
DELETE table 
FROM table 
WHERE (cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on, data_elab) IN  (
    SELECT cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on, MAX(data_elab) as data_elab_max
    FROM table
    GROUP BY cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

As MySQL doesn't tend to like DELETEing and SELECTing from the same table in a query, you might have to do some tweaking, something like:

```
DELETE table 
FROM table 
WHERE (cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on, data_elab) IN  (
    SELECT extraLayerOfIndirection.* 
    FROM (
       SELECT cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on, MAX(data_elab) as data_elab_max
       FROM table
       GROUP BY cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on 
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS extraLayerOfIndirection
);
```

---

Also, **it's not quite the same**, but you might want to consider this instead:

```
DELETE table 
FROM table 
WHERE (cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on, data_elab) NOT IN  (
    SELECT extraLayerOfIndirection.* 
    FROM (
       SELECT cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on, MIN(data_elab) as data_elab_max
       FROM table
       GROUP BY cod_dl, issn, variante, add_on 
    ) AS extraLayerOfIndirection
);
```

**Instead of only deleting the last of each grouping, this deletes all but the first for each grouping.** If you have a lot of repeats, and only want to preserve the first for each anyway, this could result in a much smaller result from the subquery.

Comment: You may want to index some or all of the group by fields. Also, you did not reveal the data types of the fields; if one or more are TEXT, BLOB, or very large CHAR data types, it could cause severe performance issues.

Comment: Field are super optimizing varchar with specific lenght (that is small....<10 in all cases) adding indexig can reduce performance in some situation?example SELECT?indexig affect also ram usage?we have only 3gb of ram so i'm afraid to add index and get worse all perfomance

Comment: Indexing is usually a good idea. As far as I know, MySQL will only keep as many indexes in memory as it thinks it can afford to; but I am just a long term db dev, not a formal db admin, so I am not aware of the edge cases where they can become an serious issue. But years ago, the live systems I was working with had much larger datasets, reasonable indexing, and not much more resources; and my dev copies were running in VMs with less resources than your server has.